# Set anonymous class as parameter of a function

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

I am writing an small ODM for Mongodb in PHP by PhpStorm. At the aggregate query:

```php
$value = $this->creditRepo->execute(AggregateQueryBuilder::create()->project('name', 'ts')->take(10)->toQuery(),
 new class{
   public ?string $name;
});
```

the second parameter is an anonymous class. And inside of `execute()` function:

```php
function execute(AggregateQuery $query, $class): ArrayObject
    {
        $result = $this->_collection->aggregate($query->getPipeline(), $query->getOptions());
        $returnArray = new ArrayObject();
        foreach ($result as $item){
            $itemx = App::jsonMapper()->map($item, new $class); // $itemx is instance of $class
            $returnArray->append($itemx);
        }

        return $returnArray;
    }
```

The result in caller script:

```php
 $value = $this->creditRepo->execute(AggregateQueryBuilder::create()
            ->project('name', 'ts')->take(10)->toQuery(), new class{
            public ?string $name;
        });
$d = $value->getArrayCopy();
$d[0]-> // not type hint, I want it hint to me the <name>
```

Can PhpStorm know the output of the `execute()` that I can type hint the output of it?

[Edit]
I have try with function `array_map`

```php
 $value = $this->creditRepo->execute(AggregateQueryBuilder::create()
    ->project('name', 'ts')->take(10)->toQuery());
$temp = new class{
   public ?string $name;
};
$output = array_map(static function ($item) use ($temp) {
    $temp->name = $item['name'];
    return $temp;
}, (array)$value);
$output[0]->name // type hinted
```

and I want to write a function that PhpStorm know that return like `array_map` how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you create the class with a name and give new instance as parameter? Then PHPStorm will know it's type. No need to make it anonymous.

Comment: it is aggregate query, and I don't want each query need to define class.

Comment: Very interesting. I've never seen something like this. But I think this breaks type safeness due to anonymity. What I've made so far was a model class for each table, and just gave Model::className as parameter. PDO fills that very nicely. Maybe this can be achived by `/** @var xxx */` annotations. I tried, but did not get a solution for your problem.

Comment: IDE needs to know the type (class name) for typehint via PHPDoc to work (e.g. via inline PHPDoc or alike). I'm not sure that even PhpStan/Psalm like syntax will do better with this kind of data (anon classes, especially after it has been passed through many intermediate functions/methods)...

Comment: I've stumbled on this [article](https://markbakeruk.net/2018/06/25/using-php-anonymous-classes-as-package-private-classes/) saying, too, that anonymous classes prevent type hinting. I could not find a [tracked issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=anonymous%20class%20type%20hint). Maybe you should create one.

Comment: yes, after all I release that it is no hope,